# to capture the buffer of a microphone

Tags: visual-c++, audio, directshow

I am creating a program that will record microphone audio and convert it into mp3 using the DirectShow API in Visual C++. 
There is no built in filter to convert to convert audio into MPEG Layer 3 i.e. MP3 so i want to send the mic buffer to an external library called as LAME , it will convert the data in MP3 and then i can write it to a file using a file writer.
But the problem is that i dont know how to access the buffer of the microphone , please help me i am new in directshow programming..

or tell me any other way to do it

Comment: I will copy my code here. Please help me by giving some of ur precious time by looking at the code and point out the mistakes... thanks in advance

Comment: I have uploaded my code here , pls pls download it and see it... thanks... http://www.filedropper.com/s_3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to distribute your application then I will suggest to use Sample Grabber instead of Lame DirectShow Encoder filter. This will avoid filter registration but you will need to handle conversion logic.

Regarding using LAME encoder,

1. what is the return value of hr = pOutputDevice->FindPin().
2. you can give a try using GraphEdit and check for pin properties.

Comment: the return value is of type HRESULT

Comment: I have made some changes in your code and uploaded code at http://www.filedropper.com/demo_1

1. In main function, Add the 'File Writer' before connecting pins/render
 //Default output device
 ...
 
 //Connect input to output, Mic to AudioRecoder WAV Dest filter
 ...
2. Pass pGraph to Device_Connect function and use pGraph->Render to connect the pin
3. Comment the code from main function which connects  AudioRecoder WAV Dest filter to test.wav

Comment: Dude its working :-) Thanks a lot... u r really awesome , keep up the gud work... thanks a lot

Comment: hey can i get ur email id ....??? if u dont want to post here , then u can send me an empty mail, my id is anchal_scorpio@yahoo.co.in i want to learn a few things frm u

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a [Sample Grabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You set it up with a callback object that will receive the samples. You can create a graph with just the source, the sample grabber and a Null Renderer.

Comment: hiiii, i tried to use the Sample Grabber as u said but i'm not able to find its pins by using ths statement :- hr = pOutputDevice->FindPin(bstrOutputPin,&pOut); pls help...